# As for polarization, what's the relation between 'fast \ slow axis' and 'P \ S polarization'

Tags: optics, polarization

In a polarized laser source or fiber, there is a mark called 'slow axis' or 'fast axis'. But on a polarized beam splitter, there is P-polarization and S-polarization. What's the relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: Oh actually I am wrong with the below statement. PhysicsDave's answer is a little more correct with respect to the actual question. In reference to a fast or slow axis of a laser source fast and slow refers to the divergence angles of the beam in two different direction perpendicular to the laser propagation direction. This has nothing to do with polarization. To address your question about polarizing beamsplitters I will state (in the context of my answer below) that S and P-polarization for this optic is designed with respect to the polarization reflective/transmissive surface of the beam-splitter.

I am most familiar with the terms fast/slow axis in the context of half or quarter waveplates. These are optical devices which change the polarization of incident light due to the linear birefringence of the optics themselves. These optics, in the right configuration, can allow one to change linear to elliptical and vice-versa and also to rotate the polarization vector about the optical axis.

Light typically passes through (transmits through) a waveplate at normal incidence. The waveplates birefringence is such that light with polarization aligned with the slow axis of the waveplate (which is a vector perpendicular to the optical axis whose direction is set by the crystal structure of the material the optic is made out of) will see one index of refraction, $n_s$ and light with polarization aligned with the fast axis (again an axis defined by the crystal orientation of the optic, the fast axis is at 90 degrees to the slow axis) will see a different index of refraction $n_f$. This is the definition of linear birefringence. This means that light polarized along the fast and slow axes will see slightly different phase shifts as they propagate through the optic. This phase shift can be tuned by changing the length of the birefringent crystal (hence the terms half-wave plate or quarter-wave plate for example) and the fast and slow axes can be changed with respect to the polarization of the beam by rotating the entire optic.

Thus fast and slow axis refers to a property of birefringent optics.

See [my answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/435309/what-is-the-difference-between-horizontally-vertically-polarized-light-and-s-p-p/435352#435352) for an explanation of s and p polarization. Basically s and p polarization arises when light is incident on a flat optic at an angle which is not normal to the plane of the optic. The plane of incidence can be defined as the plane which includes the $k$-vector for the incident light as well as the normal vector for the flat optic. Since the light polarization is always orthogonal to the propagation direction, a bit of geometric reasoning tells us that there is a polarization vector which is contained entirely in the plane of incidence and another polarization vector which is orthogonal to the plane of incidence. The polarization in the plane of incidence is called p-polarization and the component perpendicular to the plane is called s-polarization. Note that in the case of normal incidence the plane of incidence is undefined so all light looks sort of s-polarized. Certain optics, such as mirrors, have different reflection/transmission properties for light incidence at non-normal incidence depending on if the light is s or p-polarized.

Thus, s and p polarization refers to a polarizations of light *relative to* the normal vector of an optical surface which the light is striking.

Answer (score 0):

Fast and slow refers to the rate of divergence due to diffraction of the small laser diode cavity which is smaller in one direction than the other, the smaller the dimension the greater the divergence.  A polarized beamsplitter can be made from dichroic layers, very thin coatings that are of precise thickness to reflect or absorb wavelengths at a variety of angles, these layers however react differently based of the direction of polarization relative to the filter, there are spec sheets for example on the Thorlabs website for s and p reflectivity.